# Beyond Compare - how to ignore difference between 'this is a sentence' & 'this is\n a sentence'

Tags: beyondcompare

I want to know if Beyond Compare could treat the following as unimportant difference?

Left: 
this is a sentence

Right: 
this is {change to another line} a sentence

I thought maybe I could define something like '\n' or '\r\n' as unimportant text using regular expressions, but seems the tool doesn't support searching '\n' or '\r\n'...Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you should match line break + spaces as an unimportant text. The regex will be like "\s*\n\s*".

Comment: doesn't work, I tried searching with only a '\n' the tool searched nothing..

Comment: did you search for regex, didn't you?

Comment: @enkryptor  I did enable the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond Compare can't ignore line break differences.

The following will always show as a difference:

```
one two

one
two
```

Ignoring line break differences is on the feature wish list for a future version of Beyond Compare, but it doesn't have a scheduled release date.

Ignoring other types of text differences is described in the article [Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3)

Comment: Nice to hear a voice from Scooter! Do let me know when the feature is schedule.

Comment: Also I did learn how to define unimportant text from review the definitions about how it did for C/C++, then the idea to define '\n' as a 'comment' came up.